# Warning of incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

I have this block written for a hash function:

```
#include "debug.h"
#include "hash.h"

unsigned hash_add(unsigned char *name)
{
unsigned h;
for(h=0;*name;h+=name++);
return h;
}
```

I keep getting a :

```
hashadd.c:7:17: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled  by default]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last  expression  of ``` for``h+=name++ ``` is assigning address (`name` is of type `unsigned char *`) to `h` (of type `unsigned int`). change it to

```
 for(h = 0; *name; h += *name++);  
                        ^Dereference the pointer before assigning to h.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not write the code in a natural way by keeping the hash initialization, the iteration, and the accumulation separate?

```
unsigned hash_add(const unsigned char *name) {
    unsigned h = 0;
    for(; *name; name++) h += *name;
    return h;
}
```